# How to make Button width into 100% when bootstrap navbar toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several buttons dropdown, and I would want to know how to toggle navigation buttons into a width 100 %.

For example, here we can see that buttons do not occupy all the space :
[example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lachlan/398kj/)

And here is my code :

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle navbar-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Catégories <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Filtres <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Filtre 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Filtre 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>        
        <div class="btn-group navbar-right navbar-btn" role="group" aria-label="">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher"> 
        </form>
      </div>
```

Anybody has the solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

looking at your current code, you can add the following css:

```
.navbar-btn,.navbar-btn .btn{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It Worked @gaurav5430, I tried in the jsfiddle provided above. Thanks for info.